# creating static variable in php whose value remains persistent during all request

Tags: php, static

I have a class in which i have a static variable once i have initialize that variable i dont want that variable to be reinitialized. rather i want it to increment by one. here is the code snippet.

```
<?php
class staticTest{
    static $i=0;

    function __construct() {
        $this->i=$this->i+1;
        echo "i==>$this->i";
    }
 }
?>

and below is the index.php file.
<?php
require_once "staticTest.php";
$test=new staticTest();
?>
```

everytime i hit index.php in browser it always gives me output as i==>1.
what is the way in php to store the value persistently.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

Remember that PHP is a script language - interpreter runs your code and then it dies. Which clears all data that is not stored externally.
So you want to save that variable in database or file!

Answer (score 0):

Page reload will reset all variables. Use PHP SESSION for persistent.

$_SESSION[i] = 0;

$_SESSION[i] += 1;